# Titanium Appcelerator communication with webview stops working when angular app is running

Tags: angular, webview, titanium, appcelerator

We are building a angular webapp wrapped in titanium (presented through Webview) and while the two way communication between webview included scripts and titanium works when angular app is not running, but when I enable it, the communication with `Ti.App.fireEvent` & `Ti.App.addEventListener` from titanium to webview stops working for some reason while I can freely send events from angular to titanium with no problems. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: We have this same problem. We got it working with `$sceDelegateProvider.strictMode(false)` previously, but as of today this no longer seems to be working.

Comment: Sorry, that should be `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false)`